# operand order in * operator overload

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm writing a vec3 class for my game physics engine.

I've made an operator overload to allow me to multiply a vector by a scalar (to scale the vector):

```
const vec3 operator*( const real n ) const
{
    return vec3(
        m_x * n,
        m_y * n,
        m_z * n
    );
}
```

This works correctly, *if* I use the correct order in my calculation:

```
float rImpulse;
vec3 vContactNormal;
...
vec3 vImpulse = vContactNormal * rImpulse;
```

if I change the order of multiplication (e.g. if I put the scalar first in the calculation), then compiler doesn't like this and highlights it as an error.

Can I update my vec3 class, so that order of multiplication doesn't matter?  How?
(I'll probably slap my forehead when I see the answer!)

**Update**

I've removed my original operator overload from the vec3 class and placed the following two operator overloads outside the vec3 class:

```
const vec3 operator*( const vec3 & v, const real r )
{
    return vec3( 
        v.x() * r, 
        v.y() * r, 
        v.z() * r 
    );
}
const vec3 operator*( const real n, const vec3 & v )
{
    return v * n;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to declare a free operator, outside the class (or inside, as a `friend`):

```
const vec3 operator*( const real n, vec3 v )
{
    //no need to re-implement, since you already have v * n defined
    return v * n;
}
```

The reason is that, when declared as a class member, the first operator is implicitly `this`, so you basically have defined `vec3 * real`.

Comment: if the operator is outside the class, what effect would the final const keyword have?

Comment: :)  no problem!  Thanks for your response.  I'll accept your answer after the required 13 minutes or so..

Comment: There are good reasons that both versions of operator* should be declared outside the class. Arguments in the first position are treated differently than arguments in the second position for a binary operator defined inside a class. To avoid this declare symmetric binary operators outside of the class.

Comment: @jahhaj Would you like to explain more precisely how the parameters are "treated differently" please? Could you for example add a reference to the related C++ specification, if possible?